# Context problem, SPAppToken is null after redirect

Tags: csom, spcontext

I have  a provider hosted (MVC/C#/CSOM) addin. In this addin I have a homecontroller with an index-page. The page(Page A) has links to another page on the same web application (VS project) ("Page B").

These links includes the  querystring parameters (SPHostUrl, SPProductNumber, SPAppWebUrl, SPLanguage, SPClientTag) that I got from the original request (home controller).

BUT: When I get to the controller of "Page B" and try to re-create the context is null.

```
var thisWillBeNull = CurrentSharePointProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext()
```

Which is fine I guess, but When I dig deeper the code of SharePointContext.cs It tries to create a new context in

```
TokenHelper.GetContextTokenFromRequest()
```

, it looks for either a qstring parameter or a form parameter named (in my case) "SPAppToken". which does not exist. I see that it does exist as a form parameter in the original request (to "Page A")

So what Im actually asking is, should a simple html-link be so cumbersome? Am I missing something? Ive seen samples where they store the context in session, but I try to avoid this. Does anyone know how you are supposed to handle context in regards to jumping between pages?